# What is a reasonable value for SD card size for AVDs?

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

I see that when I set up my AVDs (not really knowing what I was doing, just following an online tutorial or something), I gave the SD cards a value of 100 MiBs. Is this a reasonable setting? Should I be using something like 8 GiBs instead, or does it matter?

Comment: i think it depends upon your need...Actually this memory is used to store external data.

Comment: I use 40 MBytes and am quite happy. If I were to write an app that stores more on SDCard then I'd surely used a larger size in accordance to expected data amounts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're writing a game with lots of resources you probably have to give it a higher value. Choose the size depending on your game. If you're just developing an usual app which doesn't require too much or no external memory you even can create just a 10MB sd card. Keep in mind that eclipse creates a sdcard.img which has the size you have entered, no matter how much is actually stored on the virtual sdcard.

I'm not sure but I guess that the size of the sdcard also has a little impact on the booting t time. So 8GB is too much, you'll never use it.

I always create a 10-100MB virtual sd card

Hope it helps a little

Answer (score 2):

I give it 32MB and it works fine.. no problems I think it is the maximum value that can be stored or something...

Comment: What do the different abbreviations stand for? The AVD Manager has KiB, MiB, and GiB. I assume "KiB" is Kilobyte and "GiB" is Gigabyte, but is "MiB" Migabytes or what?

Comment: yes it does sound like the will smith movie right. Min stands for mega bytes. It's not so small enough that even your app fits in. Or it is not big enough so that you would want to waste te extra memory by giving it to the avd. So go with 32 Mb normally and if you have got a huge number of images then go for 64 or 128 for game development.

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere from 10-100MB seems to work fine. :)