# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR] when trying to install android apk package using adb for platform 4.1

Tags: android

I generated an apk package for my android application. and I tried to install the package (apk) on android platform 4.1 (level 16) using the **adb** command but it genrates error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]
```

when trying to run with eclipse (run button) for the same platform (4.1 level 16) it works without a problems

this behaviour is not reproduced for platform 2.1 and platform 3.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean: Failure \[INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744298/what-does-this-mean-failure-install-failed-container-error)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to make changes in `AndroidManifest.xml`. The change which you need to do is. Change :

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Where do I find the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 15):

This will happen if `android:installLocation` is set to `"preferExternal"` and you have an AVD with a too small SD card. Increase the size of the SD card or change `installLocation` to `auto` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: There is a separate thread on the subject of emulator SD card size here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260625/what-is-a-reasonable-value-for-sd-card-size-for-avds

Comment: i liked the explanation here than the first post. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when I deleted my app after changing the MainActivity's name. idk if the app didn't install due to space issues or the phone thought the package is corrupt but **deleting the dalvik cache and rebooting** solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR is also returned when trying to install an apk that contains native libraries compiled for a different architecture.

Try running "logcat" from the "adb shell" after you get the error. If it reports a java IOException "Failed to extract native code" then you need to install the apk on an avd created for the native library architecture, or include native libraries in your apk for the architecture on your avd/device.

Answer (score 1):

My issue got solved by wiping the emulator data

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to change manifest of the build, so for me was the solution unmount SD card, install app and then mount it back.

Answer (score 0):

i change `installLocation="auto"` in manifest but not work. I found problem in something wrong with my sdcard.

So, i change `android:installLocation="preferExternal` to `internalOnly`. 
It work for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing your app on an emulator, I'd recommend wiping the emulator's data and starting it again:

1 - In Android Studio, navigate to the AVD Manager (Tools -> AVD Manager).

2 - Next to the emulator in question, click the drop-down menu on the Actions column.

3 - Click "Wipe Data" and "Cold Boot Now".

Remember to always keep your tools up to date, including Android Studio, Android SDK, and Expo CLI, as this might resolve the issue as well.