# Fail to install random APKs on Android

Tags: android, installation, apk, failed-installation

I'm running AICP on my Nexus 5, with android 5.1.1. I've been trying to install a few APKs I've found online, and I always get the same error which is Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR].
I see other people online who have been able to install them, so I'm unsure why mine is failing. Although it only seems to happen with some APK files and not others. Is there anyway I can figure out more on why it would fail to install on my device?

If it helps I've tried running the APK files on phone and through ADB and same problem.
I've tried running my own APK files (signed) and they work perfect.
Unknown sources is definitely allowed. Also free space is about 6GB at the moment, so don't think thats the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around for the installation problem! Due to the help from varunkr, it does seem to be a storage problem from what I can tell. I was able to get it working though by changing the default install location of my device. Basically I had to do the following:

1. Connect my device to my computer with adb, rooted etc
2. I started root by typing `adb root`
3. Changed the default install location to internal by going `adb shell pm set-install-location 1` in console.
4. Typed `adb install applicationName.apk` and everything work perfectly!!

I'm not sure if you want to place the default application installation back afterwards by placing it back to auto as follows: `adb shell pm set-install-location 0`

But by doing this I was able to get the application to install, and am happy I can get around it now.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when `android:installLocation` is set to `"preferExternal"` and your AVD has a too small SD card. You have to increase the size of the SD card or change installLocation to auto in AndroidManifest.xml as below, but I think you can't that.

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Also please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260625/what-is-a-reasonable-value-for-sd-card-size-for-avds)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help mate. The problem is the APK files I'm running are from around the internet and not my own so I wouldn't have access to the manifest, would this likely mean I won't be able to install the application since I wouldn't be able to change it? Cheers

Comment: Do you have an SD card on it?

Comment: Unfortunately the nexus 5 doesn't support an SD card, so its just the storage it came with. I have a feeling this might be the biggest reason why it won't install?

Comment: Yeah I think that too, cause the apk has been forced to be installed on the SD card, try it with some other android device which has an SD card, and if you feel my answer was helpful then please upvote it (even if you don't accept it) :-)